Looking for instructions for Blok Bots 9337 SPY
Where can I find the instruction manual for Mega Bloks Transforming Blok Bots set 9337 SPY?

To save future would-be answerers some time, the instructions for 9337 are not included in this repository: https://github.com/TheProgrammer163/megabloks-instructions
